# added migration , but database is not created

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-migrations

migration is added and the connection string is correct but the database is not created
what should i do 
help me please

i closed the sql server and  re-opened it but nothing is changed

my connection string :

```js
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;
      Initial Catalog=Final_BD;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR3Qf.png

when i try updata-database it shows me an error message :

" A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) "

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oQOR.png

Comment: Wee need some more information.  Can you provide any logs? Migration from what to... ?

Comment: Have you applied the migration with update-database?

Comment: no , first thing : Ebable-Migrations and then add-Migration and it worked in my console it showed me a succes message and a new folder "Migration" has been added to my project ! but when i go to the database nothing is added ? i  run the project and it shows ann exception

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your connection string as:

```
"Data Source=.\SQLSERVER;
      Initial Catalog=Final_BD;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Answer (score 0):

when i try updata-database it shows me an error message :

" A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) "

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oQOR.png

Comment: You should edit your question with this information rather than wirting it as an answer.

Comment: oh ! yeah u're right ! i forgot to do it sorry , i'm going to edit it